# How many bases can be formed given a set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, change-of-basis

Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ be a set of vectors such that the generated vector space has dimension $r$. How many different bases with dimension $r$ can be formed from these vectors?
Don't understand the downvote. This is an interesting question. Lets say I am interested out of curiosity.

**Edit**:
To make it more concrete, here is the context, in which I would like to address this question:

Let $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ be the first $n$ primes. Then $\log(p_1),\cdots,\log(p_n)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Consider the numbers $1 \cdots n$ and compute the vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ with respect to the basis $\log(p_1),\cdots,\log(p_k)$ where $k = \Pi(n)$ and $\Pi$ is the prime counting function. 
I would like to know, how many different bases one can form from these vectors. Let $b(n)$ be this number, then for example:
$b(2) = 1, b(3)=1 , b(4) = 2, b(5) = 2, b(6) = b(7) = 5$.

Here are the numbers, which form the $5=b(7)$ different bases for $1,\cdots,7$:

```
[{2, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5, 7}, {3, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7}]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is any set of $r$ of these vectors linearly independent?

Comment: If so, it's just $\begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: No, that would be easy and I would not have asked.

Comment: As to the down vote, it is most likely due to the lack of context, (why are you interested in this problem), and more importantly some indication of what you tried yourself.

Comment: In general it would depend. In some cases, the answer could just be "1", e.g. imagine if you have to pick just the first $r$ vectors (since the last $n-r$ are all $\mathbf{0}$). You can try experimenting with some small numerical examples and see what seems to happen.

Comment: I know this example. the question was meant to think about on what it in general depends